# How to set setInterval period as variable and to remove waiting time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with checkbox in each row. When the checkboxes are checked, the function will loop through to update the status of each row.

here is my working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qJdaA/2/
I used `setInterval()` to loop the function. as the table is dynamic, i do not know how long the list is going to be. so i set the period as a variable `index*4000` as follow:

```
$('#monitor').click(function () {
    $('#monitor').attr('disabled','true');
    bigloop=setInterval(function () {
    var checked = $('#status_table tr [id^="monitor_"]:checked');
        if (checked.index()==-1){
            $('#monitor').attr('disabled','true');

        }else{
    (function loop(i) {
    $('#monitor').removeAttr('disabled');
        //monitor element at index i
        monitoring($(checked[i]).parents('tr'));

        //delay
        setTimeout(function () {
            //when incremented i is less than the number of rows, call loop for next index
            if (++i < checked.length) loop(i);
        }, 3000);

    }(0)); //start with 0

    }

}, index*4000);
```

however, the problem is that it will wait for the first loop to get over without doing anything. let say i have 10 items in the list, then it will wait for 40 seconds before doing its task. How can i eliminate that problem?

Then if out of the 10 items, only 1 row is checked, i have to wait 40 seconds to update just that one row, which is inefficient.

I have tried to set `var clength = checked.length` and use it to multiply with 4000. but it won't work. Why and how should i do it?

Comment: Why are you even using a timeout or interval?  Why not just run the code immediately?  We need to understand what you're trying to accomplish and why in order to know what to suggest.

Comment: timeout to set a delay between query for each entry. setinterval to loop the whole thing over - so that i can monitor the status continuosly. i've attached the fiddle link above. here's the link in case u didnt notice http://jsfiddle.net/qJdaA/2/

Answer (score 0):

Example how to remove interval

```
<script>
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
function myTimer()
{
  // do things here
}
function myStopFunction()
{
// clear interval here
clearInterval(myVar);
}
</script>
```

Or

```
<script>
    var myVar=setInterval(myTimer,1000);
    function myTimer()
    {
      // do things here
    }
    function myStopFunction()
    {
    // clear interval here
    clearInterval(myVar);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: i didn't mention i want to clear the interval :( i want to change the interval and remove"extra waiting time"