# How to append image using jQuery .append()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I could append a string to my table to show the status as such

```
$('#test').empty().append("on")
```

but it would be better if i can display an image instead of a string. i tried this:

```
$('#test').empty().append(<img src="/static/on.png" height="64px" width="64px">)
```

but it's not working. How should i do it?

Comment: The entire `<img />` tag needs to be in quotes. `$.append('<img src="..." />')`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Missing quotes:

```
$('#test').empty().append('<img src="/static/on.png" height="64px" width="64px">');
```

Since you are emptying and appending item. you could do this instead. `.html` will replace the whole content of your selector with image item. Later on if you want to append to this div you can do `.append(...);`

```
$('#test').html('<img src="/static/on.png" height="64px" width="64px">');
```

If you are planning to `empty` and append image then `.html()` is the best approach for you.

[See Ref for .html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: It would still need quotes. And the `$` sign. :)

Comment: @PSL could you help me take a look at this question as well? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411085/how-to-set-setinterval-period-as-variable-and-to-remove-waiting-time

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
$('<img />', {
    src: 'test.png',
    width: '200px',
    height: '100px'
}).appendTo($('#empty').empty())
```

Comment: Thanks again Arun! Could you help me take a look at this problem here too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411085/how-to-set-setinterval-period-as-variable-and-to-remove-waiting-time :)

Comment: with this code, img becomes `style="width:200px; height:100px"` attribute

Comment: I need to add style background-image but it doesnt get inside the style parameter. 
`$('<li />', {
      background-image: 'url("'+tweet.photoUrl+'")',
      width: '134px',
      height: '134px'
}).appendTo($('.tweets'));`

Wont understand background-image

Answer (score 3):

You need to surround the HTML to be appended with quotes:

```
$('#test').empty().append('<img src="/static/on.png" height="64px" width="64px">');
```

I used single quotes here because you already have double quotes in the HTML, so they would escape the string if you used doubles to surround it.